# sklearn.manifold.TSNE TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32'))...)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have run the `sklearn.manifold.TSNE` example code from the sklearn documentation, but I got the error described in the questions' title.

I have already tried updating my sklearn version to the latest one (by `!pip install -U scikit-learn`) (scikit-learn=1.0.1). However, the problem is still there.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

- python = 3.7.12
- sklearn= 1.0.1

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
X = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
X_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2, learning_rate='auto',
              init='random').fit_transform(X)
X_embedded.shape
```

The error line happened in:

```
X_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2, learning_rate='auto',
              init='random').fit_transform(X)
```

Error message:

```
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')
```

Comment: I have the same issue, it looks like a bug in scikit-learn. The problem seems to come from `learning_rate='auto'`, if I delete it then the code works as expected.

Comment: @FlaviaGiammarino Remove `learning_rate='auto' ` is work for me!! Thanks you sooooooooo much!!

Comment: @FlaviaGiammarino 
BTW
Thx for correcting my question to more fluent one!!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Delete `learning_rate='auto'` solved my problem.

Thanks @FlaviaGiammarino comment!!

Comment: Why? What was the reason?

Comment: yeah, why though,,,,,

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to update your version of `scikit-learn`:

`pip install -U scikit-learn`

In `scikit-learn=1.2.2` this issue is resolved. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with 'auto' value of learning rate. Looks like a bug in this version of sklearn, cause all of string values are not acceptable for this parameter; With float value for example `learning_rate = 100`, there would be no problem.